# #1146 - table doesn't exist but showing in sidebar in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, apache2, phpmyadmin

I copy my database files from windows

**wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/data**

into my ubuntu

**/var/lib/mysql/**

Folders of my **database_name** and **ibdata1**, **ib_logfile0**, **ib_logfile1** files.
Now my all databases and tables are visible into **phpmyadmin** but when selecting any table, it shows `table doesn't exist`

How to get back my all the data

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWLoa.png) is the screenshot.

Comment: First I would check if the file system permissions in /var/lib/mysql/ are correct for the mysql system user to access your data

Comment: I have run this command.

`$ sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/`

Comment: Have you considered dumping the database using mysql tooling, rather than copying the folder structure? It sounds like you may not have all the files needed, are there any errors (other than "table doesn't exist") in your mysql logs? Also, a silly question, but did you restart mysql after copying and chown'ing the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Googling a lot I found the answer.

> Restart your mysql

`sudo mysql stop`

`sudo mysql start`

Refresh the **phpmyadmin** page

Comment: Thank you for posting this question and answer. Very illogic that restarting an sql server solves the problem of a table missing in a database import.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem in ubuntu 18.2 using >> sudo chown -R mysql:mysql var/mysql/